# apachectl restart throwing failure

Tags: centos

My server was working last night, this morning I can no longer hit it. So I attempted a restart but it fails. Can you see why from this message?

```
[jcaruso001@antlet11 ~]$ sudo apachectl restart
[sudo] password for jcaruso001:
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[jcaruso001@antlet11 ~]$ systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-10-18 09:53:09 PDT; 23s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 22923 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 22922 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22922 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[jcaruso001@antlet11 ~]$
```

I have access logs from yesterday but no error logs or access logs from today.

/var/log/httpd

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   1146 Oct  9 03:30 error_log-20161009
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  81758 Oct  9 03:30 access_log-20161009
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   1276 Oct 11 19:55 error_log-20161016
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      0 Oct 16 03:49 access_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      0 Oct 16 03:49 error_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 111750 Oct 17 22:40 access_log-20161016
```

Comment: Check the Apache logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think that update above is what your looking for.

Comment: use `journalctl -xe` to view the logs